# shell script is not counting

Tags: shell, counting

Inside my script I have a variable that I would like to count and when it reaches a certain value I would like to change another parameter, for this I had tested several ways, none of them working. Off course that the variable is initialized on the begining of the program with 0.

```
(( count++ ))
let count=count+1
count=$((count+1))
let count++
count=$(($count+1))
count=$[ $count+1 ]
count=$[$count+1]
count=[$count+1]
count=$count+1
```

None of this option has worked and I don't understand why.
Can someone help me on this topic.

Thanks,

Comment: We need a [mcve] showing how you tested this code and letting others reproduce the result. Many of these things **always** work in any POSIX-compliant shell, but if you're say, piping to a `while read` loop, then you're throwing away the results.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/ekcXlM running each of your commands in an online interpreter -- everything but the last two works in modern bash (though the third is the best choice for portability reasons, or `(( ++count ))` if you're only targeting bash -- note the preincrement, not postincrement, so `set -e` won't break your code on some shell releases as described in [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises)).

Comment: "none of them working" is not a particularly useful description of the error.  Is an error message being generated?  Is the shell okay with the syntax?  Are you printing the value and it is not being incremented as you expect?

Comment: Inside my code I've:

count=0
MY_STRING_LIST="topic1,topic2,topic3,setopic4"
FIELD_SEPARATOR=$IFS
IFS=,

for i in $MY_STRING_LIST;
do
 echo "count" "$count"

 count=$((count+1))
 if [ "$count" -eq 3 ]; then
  var_count=1
  echo "$var_count"
 fi
done

The error that I have is:
syntax error: `count=$' unexpected

Comment: I found the issue.
Before my script starts, I have 5 lines for commenting some stuff, I always used this sort of layout and never faced issues.
In this one since I put in the first line #!/bin/bash insted of my comments, it started working.